# Adding a string to a column across multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

In my table I have a column called ImportKey. I want to update this column and add an A either before or after each number. So changing this:

```
ImportKey
---------
2345
1353
2474
4762
---------
```

to this:

```
ImportKey
---------
A2345
A1353
A2474
A4762
---------
```

or this:

```
ImportKey
---------
2345A
1353A
2474A
4762A
---------
```

The column is a string value, I'm just not sure of the syntax to update multiple rows and add something to each of them. Any help?

Comment: Update MyTable set ImportKey= 'A'+ ImportKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepend or append the letter:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1
SET dbo.Table1.ImportKey = 'A' + dbo.Table1.ImportKey
```

[**Prepend**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3695/1/0) - [**Append**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3695/2/0)

[UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)